# Image-based panoromic localization MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is there any technique, that uses a model of the environment formed by two panoramic cylindrical images taken at different locations, and a planar image taken at the current position?

I need to compare the planar image with panoramic images to tell the robot about its location.

This is my code so far, which is an attempt to use [the RANSAC method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC), but it does not work.

```
[x1, T1] = normalise2dpts(x1);
[x2, T2] = normalise2dpts(x2);

s = 4;  % Minimum No of points needed to fit a homography.

fittingfn = @wrap_vgg_homography2d;
distfn    = @homogdist2d;
degenfn   = @isdegenerate;

% x1 and x2 are 'stacked' to create a 6xN array for ransac
[H, inliers] = ransac([x1; x2], fittingfn, distfn, degenfn, s, t);

% Now do a final least squares fit on the data points considered to
% be inliers.
Hlin = vgg_H_from_x_lin(x1(:,inliers), x2(:,inliers));
H = vgg_H_from_x_nonlin(Hlin,x1(:,inliers), x2(:,inliers));


% Denormalise
H = T2\H*T1;    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Function to evaluate the symmetric transfer error of a homography with
% respect to a set of matched points as needed by RANSAC.

function [inliers, H] = homogdist2d(H, x, t)

x1 = x(1:3,:);   % Extract x1 and x2 from x
x2 = x(4:6,:);    

% Calculate, in both directions, the transfered points    
Hx1    = H*x1;
invHx2 = H\x2;

% Normalise so that the homogeneous scale parameter for all coordinates
% is 1.

x1     = hnormalise(x1);
x2     = hnormalise(x2);     
Hx1    = hnormalise(Hx1);
invHx2 = hnormalise(invHx2); 

d2 = sum((x1-invHx2).^2)  + sum((x2-Hx1).^2);
inliers = find(abs(d2) < t);    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Function to determine if a set of 4 pairs of matched  points give rise
% to a degeneracy in the calculation of a homography as needed by RANSAC.
% This involves testing whether any 3 of the 4 points in each set is
% colinear. 

function r = isdegenerate(x)

x1 = x(1:3,:);    % Extract x1 and x2 from x
x2 = x(4:6,:);    

r = ...
iscolinear(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),x1(:,3)) | ...
iscolinear(x1(:,1),x1(:,2),x1(:,4)) | ...
iscolinear(x1(:,1),x1(:,3),x1(:,4)) | ...
iscolinear(x1(:,2),x1(:,3),x1(:,4)) | ...
iscolinear(x2(:,1),x2(:,2),x2(:,3)) | ...
iscolinear(x2(:,1),x2(:,2),x2(:,4)) | ...
iscolinear(x2(:,1),x2(:,3),x2(:,4)) | ...
iscolinear(x2(:,2),x2(:,3),x2(:,4)
```

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a MCVE ( **a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code** ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & **to show your will to respect** other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: @user3532509 What does your tag `dip` mean? Digital image processing or Density independent pixel?

Comment: dip is dipimage toolbox used in matlab

Comment: I have made an attempt to improve the question formatting. But I do not know the RANSAC method, or what is wrong with your code. Please provide more details about where your code is going wrong. It would be really good if you also provided some test images, because this is going to be hard to fix without two panoramic images and a planar one to match. Very few people here will have that data - but with the data it may become an interesting question (lots of us like robots!)